# How to use same navbar in reactjs to do the work of two navbar?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have to make an admin portal in which I have two home pages, so I need two navbars with different options and with different links.

But what I want to do is use the same navbar to work as others if we log in to another page.

```
function OrgAdminNavbar(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.header_block}>
        <img src={Logo} className={styles.logo} />
        <strong className={styles.heading}>TalawaAdmin</strong>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.left_block}>
        <li>
          <a href="/orghome">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/orgmember">Member</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">LogOut</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default OrgAdminNavbar;
```

this is my first navbar

```
function SuperAdminNavbar(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.header_block}>
        <img src={Logo} className={styles.logo} />
        <strong className={styles.heading}>TalawaAdmin</strong>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.left_block}>
        <li>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/supermember">People</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/superorg">Organization</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/">LogOut</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SuperAdminNavbar;
```

And this is my second navbar basically I want to merge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of names and urls to a generic Navbar component:

```
interface NavbarProps {
  targets: { url: string, name: string }[]
}

function Navbar({ targets }: NavbarProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.header_block}>
        <img src={Logo} className={styles.logo} />
        <strong className={styles.heading}>TalawaAdmin</strong>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.left_block}>
        {targets.map(({ name, url}) => <li key={name}><a href={url}>{name}</a></li>)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<Navbar
  targets={[
    { name: 'Home', url: '/'},
    { name: 'People', url: '/supermember'},
    { name: 'Organisation', url: '/superorg'}
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: Binding element 'targets' implicitly has an 'any' type. this is the error it is getting can you please help me

Comment: @YasharthDubey Oh, right, Typescript. I have edited my answer to give a type to the navbar props.

Comment: ok thanks for your help please upvote the question

Comment: One more thing how can i test the functioning of the URLs here

Comment: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator this is another error I am getting @Altareos

Answer (score 1):

You can take the urls as props, and can use it twice in the parent file.

Comment: could you please give some pseudo code for this and please upvote the question

Comment: @altareos just now posted the coded, you can see it from there :)